# How do I ignore special characters in sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following code:

```
ToString="java.extended.properties=-XX\:MaxPermSize\=128m -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/tibco/repo/RVRepoProcessBridge,handleServerHeartbeat"
sed -i "s@.*java.extended.properties.*@$ToString@g" "$ToFile"
```

It does amend the `ToFile` but the string doesn't have the 2 `\`'s in it. How do I ensure that these are recognized as part of the string?

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?  There is only one '\' as far as I can see, you need to edit your post to make the text from "ToString" down to the sed command all formatted as code.
(I have a possible answer I shall post anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the '.' in the sed regex, to be more accurate.

And for the ToString variable:

1. escape the '\' so that shell interpreter will expand to a single slash (in the third point below),
2. when defining this variable, use single quotes so it is not expanded, and
3. expand (by double quoting) when using it within sed, to get the correct end result.

So, something like this should work:

```
ToString='java.extended.properties=-XX\\:MaxPermSize\\=128m -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/tibco/repo/RVRepoProcessBridge,handleServerHeartbeat'

sed -i "s@.*java\.extended\.properties.*@""$ToString""@g" "$ToFile"
```

Comment: The output file has the following value; java.extended.properties=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/tibco/repo/RVRepoProcessBridge,handleServerHeartbeat
it should have;java.extended.properties=-XX\:MaxPermSize\=128m -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/tibco/repo/RVRepoProcessBridge,handleServerHeartbeat   - I have tried \\

Comment: I've edited my response, so that should give you the result you need.

Comment: changed the code as suggested and still get the following  java.extended.properties=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/tibco/repo/RVRepoProcessBridge,handleServerHeartbeat

Comment: I've just tested the two script lines in my answer, and I get this:  `java.extended.properties=-XX\:MaxPermSize\=128m -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/tibco/repo/RVRepoProcessBridge,handleServerHeartbeat` which I believe is what you need, no?

Comment: Also, do you have this code in a script file, and if so, do you have a "`#!`" at the top of the file?

Comment: works now thanks I missed the double \\ in ToString - thanks for your help